# Не удается получить доступ к сайту

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Всем добрый день. Очень прошу о вашей помощи. Написал сайт и есть страница, которая отвечает за `insert` в ms sql, и, если я пытаюсь ввести больше 40-ка строк текста в базу, то сайт начинает долго думать и выдает такую ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часть кода:

```
string str = FileUpload1.FileName;
string path = "~//uploads//" + str.ToString();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
string str2 = FileUpload2.FileName;
string path2 = "~//uploads//" + str2.ToString();
```

и т. д.